# CakePHP - Change the $useTable var from within the Model

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3

### Question:

How do I change the $useTable from within the model?

I would like to change the $useTable value in my beforeSave (or save) method in the model based on data passed in the save. Is this possible?

---

### What I've already tried:

- I tried changing `$this->useTable` but it didn't work. It changed the actual variable, but it turns out that useTable value is cached when `$Model->save` is used.

I know I can change this value from the Controller before calling save, but I would rather handle this in my model based on the data passed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using `$this->setSource('table_name')` in the `beforeSave` method inside the model, and it effected the final save. I had seen `setSource` used from a controller, but didn't think to use it inside the model.